# OpenCV: Map polygon to rect

Tags: python, opencv

I have an input image and region on it defined by a polygon with 4 points `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`. Now I need to map those 4 polygon points to an upright rectangle with the same width and height (correcting orientation and perspective of the poly). How do I best go about that with `cv2`?

Ideally this transform should be reversible, so that you can also map back from `Image 2` to `Image 1` coordinate space.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps `getPerspectiveTransform` and then apply it with `warpPerspective`? To give further details, i would be useful to have a sample image with the point coordinates, and some illustration of what exactly you expect as the result.

Comment: @ErikAigner Have you tried what Dan Mašek suggested? It's pretty straight forward if you have the coordinates of both the polygon and the rectangle.

Answer (score 4):

I found this example [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/).

The input `pts` must be ordered clockwise top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left.

```
def four_point_transform(image, pts):
    # obtain a consistent order of the points and unpack them
    # individually
    rect = order_points(pts)
    (tl, tr, br, bl) = rect

    # compute the width of the new image, which will be the
    # maximum distance between bottom-right and bottom-left
    # x-coordiates or the top-right and top-left x-coordinates
    widthA = np.sqrt(((br[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((br[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
    widthB = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - tl[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - tl[1]) ** 2))
    maxWidth = max(int(widthA), int(widthB))

    # compute the height of the new image, which will be the
    # maximum distance between the top-right and bottom-right
    # y-coordinates or the top-left and bottom-left y-coordinates
    heightA = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - br[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - br[1]) ** 2))
    heightB = np.sqrt(((tl[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((tl[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
    maxHeight = max(int(heightA), int(heightB))

    # now that we have the dimensions of the new image, construct
    # the set of destination points to obtain a "birds eye view",
    # (i.e. top-down view) of the image, again specifying points
    # in the top-left, top-right, bottom-right, and bottom-left
    # order
    dst = np.array([
        [0, 0],
        [maxWidth - 1, 0],
        [maxWidth - 1, maxHeight - 1],
        [0, maxHeight - 1]], dtype = "float32")

    # compute the perspective transform matrix and then apply it
    M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(rect, dst)
    warped = cv2.warpPerspective(image, M, (maxWidth, maxHeight))

    # return the warped image
    return warped
```